# How to search multiple fields in a search box in spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using spring data jpa and am writing a search function. In my model include firstName and lastName. I want my search dialog to do a search on both firstName and lastName. For example, firstName is Alen and lastName is Lee if I enter in the search box is Alen or Lee then spring still find the correct value. Is there any way to help me achieve that in spring data jpa?

**EmployeeDao**

```
package com.baotrung.springcrudjpafull.dao;

import com.baotrung.springcrudjpafull.model.Employee;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface EmployeeDao extends CrudRepository<Employee,Integer> {
        Employee findAllByFirstNameAndLastName(String firstName,String lastName);
}
```

EmployeeController

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/searchEmployee", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getEmployeeByName(@RequestParam("firstName") String firstName, @RequestParam("lastName") String lastName, ModelMap modelMap) {
        Employee employee = servicesDao.findAllByFirstNameAndLastName(firstName,lastName);
        modelMap.addAttribute("employees", employee);
        return "Employee";
    }
```

However in jsp I do not know how to pass the parameter to be able to call it. If using , only one parameter is used.So how can I find multiple fields in a search box in spring.Please help

Comment: you meant , wanna search record that matched last name "or" first name?

Comment: The question is not as much clear. Is the issue in the view (JSP) or the Dao?

Comment: @Javvano I want to find both firstName and lastName.

Comment: @Leone  I think the problem at both. I write in the repository do not know is correct and jsp side I do not know how to call to be able to look for both. Sorry for the question is not clear

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
findAllByFirstNameLikeOrLastNameLike
```

Or

```
findAllByFirstNameContainingOrLastNameContaining
```

The first one will produce a request with `like` comparation, and the second one will wrap parameters into %%

Comment: thanks. but in jsp, if I create a form search, how do I find both firstName and lastName.

Comment: If my answer is not a thing you was looking for, I will agree with other guys - your question is not clear. Sorry

Comment: thank you for understanding I just do not know in the jsp how search dialog to be passed to the 2 parameters above

Answer (score 3):

Check this out:

In repo:

```java
@Repository
public interface EmployeeDao extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {
    @Query("select e from Employee e where lower(e.firstName) like lower(concat('%', :search, '%')) " +
"or lower(e.lastName) like lower(concat('%', :search, '%'))")
    List<Employee> findByFirstNameOrLastName(@Param("search") String search);
}
```

In controller:

```java
@RequestMapping("/searchEmployee", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getEmployeeByName(@RequestParam(name = "search") String search, Model model) {
        Employee employee = servicesDao.findAllByFirstNameAndLastName(search);
        model.addAttribute("employees", employee);
        return "Employee";
    }
```

And in jsp should be similar as I did in thymeleaf:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{search}" method="get" class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control form-control-dark" type="text" placeholder="Search" name="search" aria-label="Search">
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-light" value="Search">Search</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use GET method, the parameters should be @PathVaraible instead of @RequestParam and you have to call method with `/searchEmployee/Alen/Lee`

And the controller should be;

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/searchEmployee/{firstname}/{lastname}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getEmployeeByName(@PathVariable("firstName") String firstName, @PathVariable("lastName") String lastName, ModelMap modelMap) {
        List<Employee> employee = servicesDao.findAllByFirstNameAndLastName(firstName,lastName);
        modelMap.addAttribute("employees", employee);
        return "employee";
    }
```

If you want to the user can type to search value, you need to create a html form in jsp and submit your form `/searchEmployee` uri and also controller should be

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/searchEmployee", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String getEmployeeByName(@RequestParam("firstName") String firstName, @RequestParam("lastName") String lastName, ModelMap modelMap) {
        List<Employee> employee = servicesDao.findAllByFirstNameAndLastName(firstName,lastName);
        modelMap.addAttribute("employees", employee);
        return "employee";
    }
```

And your controller method should be return jsp file name without suffix. For ex. if your jsp file name `employee.jsp`, method should be `return "employee";`

And i think the repository should be like;

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeDao extends CrudRepository<Employee,Integer> {
        List<Employee> findAllByFirstNameAndLastName(String firstName,String lastName);
}
```

But this depends on to your Employee data model. I mean if the firstname and lastname have unique constraint with both, you can return just Employee object as well

Comment: yes thank you I think the above answer by Yuriy Tsarkov is correct but I do not know how to be able to pass more than 2 parameters into the search box in jsp. If using findAllByFirstNameAndLastName it will not work.

Comment: what you exacly expect sql where clause?

Comment: Ya, @cagridursun has asked really straight question! What is a sql query you are going to achieve?